# How do I add pandas dataframes according to multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe A as follows:

[image]

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'v1' : [1,2,2],
         'v2':[2,3,4],
         'weight':[10,11,12]})
A.set_index(['v1','v2'])
```

[image]

```
B = pd.DataFrame({'v1' : [2,3,4],
         'v2' : [3,5,6],
         'weight':[20,21,22]})
B.set_index(['v1','v2'])
```

I want to add A and B with respect to their multi-index to form the below dataframe:

[image]

How do I code this..?

Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide the codes for recreating the both input dataframes

Comment: @anky_91 I edited the post.. Since I am new to this site, I am not familiar with writing tools given in this site. Please forgive me for my post being very messy.

Comment: just do `A.add(B, axis='index', fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that e.g. `A.set_index(['v1','v2'])` creates only a temporary result,
with new MultiIndex, but leaves the index in the original DataFrame
as it was before.

So I assume that you executed `A.set_index(['v1','v2'], inplace=True)`,
the same for *B* DataFrame.

To generate your sum, run a **single** instruction:

```
pd.concat([A,B]).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```

## Edit

If you have both DataFrames with "normal" index (just as you created them),
you can run also a single instruction:

```
pd.concat([A,B]).groupby(['v1', 'v2']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Join `A` and `B`:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'v1' : [1,2,2],
         'v2':[2,3,4],
         'weight':[10,11,12]}).set_index(['v1', ' v2'])

B = pd.DataFrame({'v1' : [2,3,4],
         'v2' : [3,5,6],
         'weight':[20,21,22]}).set_index(['v1', 'v2'])

C = A.join(B, how='outer', lsuffix='_A', rsuffix='_B').fillna(0)
C['weight'] = C['weight_A'] + C['weight_B']
```

Result:

```
       weight_A  weight_B  weight
v1 v2                            
1  2       10.0       0.0    10.0
2  3       11.0      20.0    31.0
   4       12.0       0.0    12.0
3  5        0.0      21.0    21.0
4  6        0.0      22.0    22.0
```

Drop `weight_A` and `weight_B` if needed